# how to deletes line from a text file that are taken from another file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, sh

I have a `data.txt` file with a lot of lines in it and a `lines.txt` that contains some lines.

I want to delete all lines from `data.txt` that match any line from `lines.txt` and to save that new file as `no_dupplicate_lines.txt`.
I tried this but it does not work:

```
LC_ALL=C fgrep -v -f dupp jour_24-06.txt
```

I looking for a solution a kind of `File1 MINUS File2 => File1-File2`

Comment: provide some sample input and desired output. also, this has been asked many times, didn't you find any solution? why isn't the current approach working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this with `grep`:

```
grep -vxf lines.txt data.txt > no_dupplicate_lines.txt
```

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ cat lines.txt
Line2
Line4
AMD$ cat data.txt
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
AMD$ grep -vxf lines.txt data.txt
Line1
Line3
Line5
```

Print the lines that are not matching (`-v`) the exact lines (`-x`) from the file lines.txt (`-f lines.txt`).
See `man grep` for option details.